# Json.Encode(Model) returns empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

In ASP.NET MVC view trying to display the text from the list that is displayed one at a time.

The script does its job but for some reason Conversion List  to JSON object fails. List  object comes to a view with the correct values, but the conversion attempt returns an empty JSON object.

View:

```
@model List<WebSiteUpravitelj.Models.BlogModels.Objava>

<a href="/Blog/Objave">
<div>

<h2>Novosti</h2>

@if (Model != null)
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
         var list = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))";            
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                $('#spinNaslov').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400).text(list[i].Naslov);
                $('#spinBloger').delay(400).fadeIn(200).text(list[i].Korisnik + ', ' + list[i].Datum);
            }            
        });
    </script>
    <div id="novostiSpin">
        <h2 id="spinNaslov" style="text-align:center; color:#fed8e6;"></h2>
        <span id="spinBloger" style="float:right; color:#999898; padding:5px;"></span> 
    </div><br />       

}
else
{ 
    <p>Trenutno nema novih objava u novostima.</p>
}

</div>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult _Novosti()
    {
        List<Objava> oList = Objava.Novosti();
        return PartialView(oList);
    }
```

Model

```
public class Objava:List<Objava>
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Naslov { get; set; }
    public string Datum { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]//System.Web.Mvc;
    public string Sadrzaj { get; set; }
    public string Korisnik { get; set; }
}
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I really do not know what.

Please help.

Comment: if you're encoding to JSON, there's no reason to wrap it in double quotes. So, `var list = "@Html.Raw(...);"` becomes simply `var list = @Html.Raw(...);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I tried the above but then VS gives me syntax error on ;  in         @Html.Raw (Json.Encode (Model)); or on next line if i remove ;

Comment: Try using either `@(Html.Raw(json.Encode(model)))` or assign it to something like `String listJSON = Json.Encode(Model)` then use `var list = @listJSON;` -- For the record, i do get Razor barking at me about `;` but they're usually an error I can ignore since the generated HTML comes out correctly.

Comment: I also tried to forward the list with VIewBag and create a JSON object in the controller and pass it with ViewBag

Comment: I tried both and no results... this is String value after encoding [[],[],[]]

Comment: For the record, each of these methods returns the same result

Comment: Problem solved,
The problem was in the model.

Model Objave inherits List<Objave> and therefore at the time of creating the list each time in the object is inserted Property of List<Objave> which was empty. From there empty JSON object. When converting to JSON, other properties (which had a value) are ignored.

The solution, I removed the base List<Objave> and created static methods for creating lists.
Now everything is working.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I was goign to ask why you inherited from `List<T>` but had your properties on the list object. ;-)

Comment: I have no logical answer to this question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, The problem was in the model. Model Objave inherits List and therefore at the time of creating the list each time in the object is inserted Property of List which was empty. From there empty JSON object. When converting to JSON, other properties (which had a value) are ignored. The solution, I removed the base List and created static methods for creating lists. Now everything is working. Thank you for your time